# How to plot countours around points with different alpha level of countours

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to reproduce the attached plot on the training iris dataset with Petal.Length (x) and Sepal.Length (y). I assume it is about stat_density_2d arguments, but I was not able to reach the exact same picture.
Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map `alpha` to the calculated `level` within `stat_density2d_filled`, using `alpha = after_stat(level)` inside `aes`. Just tweak the `breaks` argument to define where you want the contour cutoffs to be. I also found that adjusting the `h` argument to set a slightly wider bandwidth than the default worked better than the default setting with this particular data set. Additionally, a call to `scale_alpha_manual` will give you fine control over the opacity of each band - here I set a sequence of six values between 0 and 1, since only the first 5 will be used, meaning that the most dense bands still won't be fully opaque and "overpower" the points.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  stat_density2d_filled(aes(alpha = after_stat(level)),
                        h = c(1, 1), breaks = c(0, 0.03, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 5)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 3) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = seq(0, 1, length = 6)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "gray80", fill = NA))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to include also the very last blue point in, please?

Comment: @PetrPapežík that's what I meant about tweaking the `breaks` to suit. The second break indicates the lowest value of density you want colored. I have adjusted this to 0.03 to include the small values around the last blue dot.. See my update.